# Can we get the remaining count in std::counting_semaphore in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, semaphore

In POSIX, we can use `sem_getvalue(sem_t* sem, int* val)` to get the remaining count of a semaphore(if no remaining, return 0 or a negative value that shows the number of waiting guys). The C++20 standard adopts `<semaphore>` but it seems that there is no equivalent function for `get_value`; So can we get it and if not, why isn't there such a thing?

Comment: I'm curious as to what exactly you would do with that information. What kind of decisions are you going to make based on the answer?

Comment: What is the use of `get_value`?  It is inherently racey (TOCTOU).

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm a novice in parallel programming and I just learn POSIX semaphore API and want to compare it with C++20 `<semaphore>`; So I don't get the point too...(In fact, I think `std::atomic` is a good enough alternative to semaphore).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. So it's legacy and never used today, right?

Comment: It is not marked as legacy  but I cannot imagine a correct usage example. Do you have one?

Comment: @o_oTurtle: The problem is that it is information which is out of date the moment you check it. Remember: you're talking about threaded access here. Any number of threads can be acquiring and releasing at any time. So by the time you get the results, they may have changed. And therefore, whatever decision you were thinking about making may no longer be valid.

Comment: Not exactly...still waiting for a useful example XD.

Comment: @NicolBolas A possible usage example I came across today is debugging a system that has seemingly hanged due to a deadlock. It seems to be a Heisenbug that disappears if I put `printf` in the threads trying to acquire the semaphore, so I'm hoping to get a better understanding of the hang state from a passive thread (probably after the hang state has already happened).